# GPUImage and camera2, android

Tags: android, android-camera, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage

in camera i used the following method: `mGPUImage.setUpCamera(camera, ...)`

Couldn't find similar method in camera2 (API21), any suggestions ?

Comment: The library probably hasn't been updated with camera2 support yet.

Comment: what about alternatives ? any framework which can be used instead of GPUImage ?

Comment: as an alternative you can use OpenGL shaders for effects. F.e. keep one shader for each effect you want to create and as camera preview frame  use GLSurfaceView which implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Answer (score 2):

You'll need for GPUImage to support camera2, or add such support yourself.

You could also investigate RenderScript for your image processing, if you don't want to set up a whole OpenGL context on your own.